# Android Java Programming

Tags: java, android, android-gridview

Hi everyone I am Beginner

Actually I have to develop like this app
If I have 12 buttons then when I click one button the message should be displayed for 10 seconds ,during this the all buttons should disappear after 10 seconds that 12 buttons should display again ?

But in this how can I display the message for 10 seconds during this. I can do that disappearing of  1 button at a time ,but  actually I need to disappear all 12 buttons at a time when message is displayed. Sorry for mentioning question as too big..

Can anyone please  help me how to do this ....

Thank You All.

Comment: please show your work?

Comment: If you are a beginner, you should read tutorials first dude. A word of advice, show some effort first please. Use GOOGLE. If you will just type "display message android" in google, the first result is the answer you are asking here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize your Toast and set as you required like this..

```
Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button One is Clicked",
            10000);
    t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    t.show();
```

and start a thread of ten seconds and set visibility gone of all button you get .

Answer (score 0):

Use a customized Toast

You can also customize the look, text, font, position, layout and time (long or short) of a standard Android `Toast` Notification.  (by provide a custom layout, style, or view).

**http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html**

If you want something more customizable you could overlay an activity or dialog, or even just a view.  However, `Toast` notifications are basically designed for this.